# La aplicación funciona en el emulador pero no en el dispositivo real (problema de permisos)

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza peticiones http y la cámara para lectura de códigos QR.

En el gradle, el compile SDK es el 31, el target es el 31 y el minimo es el 21.

Estoy convencido de que es un problema de permisos, por ello he hecho lo siguiente:

EN EL MANIFIEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
```

EN EL MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
            checkExternalStoragePermission();
        }

private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        225);
            }
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        226);
            }
        }

    }
```

Aún así, nada mas iniciar la aplicación en el movil se cierra, mientras que en el emulador corre perfectamente. Creo que es un problema del permiso de la cámara, aunque en el MainActivity no se use. He llegado a esta conclusión porque tengo otra app con la misma configuración de SDK, que corre perfectamente en ese dispositivo, que también usa internet pero que no usa la cámara. Así que el problema debe estar en los permisos de la cámara.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: quizá es que en el manifiesto no declaras el permiso de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, de todas formas estaría bien si puedes dar más información sobre la salida del logcat: `adb logcat AndroidRuntime:e *:s -v tag` con el dispositivo físico corriendo la app

Comment: Era el permiso del manifiest, muchas gracias. ¿Como hago para dar tu respuesta por buena y que se quede la pregunta contestada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta era que faltaba declarar el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE en el manifest